# Add the 'day' in the notification panel?

Tags: windows-10, calendar, windows-10-calendar-app

I use Windows 10.

The notification panel (on the lower-right corner) shows current time and date

e.g. 'PM 1:59, 2016-07-21'

Can I add 'day of the week' in this panel?

Of course I know that I can see the day simply by clicking it to see the calendar.
But I want something more simple and convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this by changing one of windows more obscure settings.

**Steps :**

- Go to the **Settings** in **Start Menu**.
- Click **Time & Language**.
- Scroll Down and then click **Additional date, time, & regional settings**.
- On the Control Panel Screen that opens, Under **Region**, Click **Change date, time, or number formats**.
- Press **Additional Settings**, which is near the bottom of the dialog box.
- Go to the **Date** Tab.
- Over there, change the Short date to **dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy**
- Click **OK** and then **OK** again.

[image]

There are many variants you could try out. You could try **dddd-M-yyyy** or **yy/MM/dddd**.